# Anticoagulation of black beans extract

Tags: biochemistry, hematology, morphology, biomedical-technology

How many ml of lithium heparin do I need to use on 2 ml blood to prevent coagulation for over 15 minutes?

I am comparing it to the 4 different dosages of black turtle bean extract that has polyphenols which I think have an anticoagulant effect.

Comment: At the very least, you will need to supply the _concentration_ of lithium heparin, or work in milligrams rather than ml.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I only have  the lithium heparin from Vacutainer, which has 75 units and 4ml. Do you think I can use that as a control?

Comment: Is that Howell units, USP, etc.?